# Do functions that are defined outside the render() method body have better render performance in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two different function definitions:

Example 1:

```
onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  //
};

render() {
  return (
    <Input onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
  );
}
```

Example 2:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Input onChange={(e) => {
      //
    }} />
  );
}
```

I know that in React.js world, code from the first example has better performance, because `onChangeHandler` will be created only once. In the second example, anonymous arrow function will be created each time of render. Does this principle work in React-Native?

Comment: Since `react-native` greatly depends on `react` for the javascript part, yes this principle will also work in `react-native`. This will also help to write cleaner and more organised code which is easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @AmmarAhmed thanks! but i didn't find any technical evidence about this, may be you have it? as far as i understand, react-native compiles to some native code, and may be some optimizations take effect during the compilation step?